# How to understand the concept of variable

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The concept of the variable is defined as:

> A variable is introduced by **the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object**. The variable's name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

The relevant concept of the declaration of an **object** is defined as:
[dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-10](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-10)

> If the decl-specifier-seq contains no typedef specifier, the declaration is called a function declaration if the type associated with the name is a function type ([dcl.fct]) and **an object declaration otherwise**.

So, consider the below code, which entities are called variable?

```cpp
class A{
  int a;  // #1  `a` can be called a variable?  
  int& rf; // #2
};

void fun(int p, int& prf){  // #3 where p can be called a variable, and how about `prf`
}


int main(){
  int data = 0; // data is absolutely called a variable 
  int& ref = data;// ref is absolutely called a variable 
}
```

I wonder whether `#1` can be called a variable? Sometimes, the name `a` is introduced by member-declaration. Hence, it's a member of class `A`. But sometimes, it is also called **member subobject**. According to the definition of terminology variable, it's introduced by a declaration of an **object**.

So, can name `a` be called variable? Is it call a member or a member subobject? If it is the latter, I think it should be called a variable. Moreover, its associated type is not **a function type**.

About `#2`, it's just a data member of class `A` and is definitely not a variable(it's a non-static data member of class `A` of reference type).

Are parameters `int p` and `int& prf` in the declaration of `fun` called variable?  According to [dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-10], their associated types are all not function types, so they should be declarations of objects. Namely, they should be called variables, Right?

Whether the rule [dcl.dcl#dcl.pre-10] still applies to **parameter declaration and member-declaration**?

Moreover, why the definition for `variable` only qualifies reference type that it shall not be a reference of a non-static member of a class? why not give a similar qualification for an object? Maybe a non-static data member other than a reference type is not an object at all? If it was, when will we call `a` a member subobject?

Please interpret these issues.

Comment: @Vuwox I'm sure that `#2` is definitely not a variable that is forbidden by the formal definition of `variable`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard is generally confused about the difference between a variable (a kind of **entity** that can, for instance, be found by name lookup) and an object (a unit of data that exists for some portion of the program’s execution).  A non-reference variable with static storage duration has exactly **one** object associated with it—not counting tricks like explicit destructor calls and placement new—but a thread-local variable can have more than one object associated with it, and a (non-reference) variable with automatic storage duration has zero or more based on how many times its function or block has been **reentered** (on however many threads) at any moment (plus any number of suspended coroutine frames as of C++20).  Non-static data members (again, that are not references) are even more arbitrary: there is an object for each for each object of the containing type, including all the cases above as well as those with **dynamic** storage duration.  (For variables and non-static data members of reference type, all the above holds *mutatis mutandis*, but we don’t have a good, separate term for “an instance of a reference-type variable”.)

The situation is even worse with base classes: if `D` inherits from `B` and `C` which each inherit from `A`, `D` has three base classes but each `D` object has **four** base class subobjects.  We don’t have a good term for “appearance of a class in the inheritance lattice of another” to capture that four-fold aspect without regard to a particular object, even though we need such a term for handling things like name lookup ambiguity.

Given the above, it’s hardly surprising that the answer to your question is going to be unsatisfactory, but here it is: a non-static data member (a “member variable”) is **never** a variable even though there can be many (sub)objects associated with it.  It can be a reference, just like `extern int &r;` (which is also not an object), which is why the definition in [basic.pre] has to exclude non-static data members when it considers “references” (by which we mean certain entities) and “objects” (by which we mean certain other entities).

Comment: Why the rule only excludes `non-static data member` for references? I think it's similar to `non-reference non-static data member`. Namely, if there is not an object of containing type, how could we use the member reference. Since it excludes `non-static member` for references, why not excludes `non-static member` for the objects?

Comment: Or do you mean that when we say a reference, it can be a non-static data member of reference type. Rather, when we say an object, it definitely can not be a non-static data member?(i.e,  a non-static data member is just a **member** of the containing class rather than an object?) Is it necessary to clarify the concept of the declaration of an object?

Comment: @jackX: Yes; I’ve misread the sentence myself in the past.  Data members (in the abstract rather than in one instance) aren’t objects, but in the current terminology they can be references, so they’re excluded in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I think to introduce a formal definition of what is a declaration of an object is important.(e.g, `extern int value`, IIUC, `value` is an object). If such a definition would exclude non-static non-reference data member from being an object, then `pointer to a completely-defined object type` wouldn't confuse someone who may misread it in the past(such as me).

Comment: @jackX: I would say that your `value` **has** a (unique) object for consistency with other entities that must have their objects rather than be them for counting reasons.  We should definitely fix the standard (though I might need a break after P1787!), but there will still be differences between, for instance, objects and object types.

Comment: **P1787** is a wonderful proposal. It has fixed a lot of obscure, arguable, underspecified issues in the current standard. As a reader, I appreciate the author of the P1787, that is you. BTW, the definition for **object types** is: An object type is a (possibly cv-qualified) type that is not a function type, not a reference type, and not cv void.  It still does not exclude member types.   Certain operators expect its operand has type `pointer to a completely-defined object type`....

Comment: We can only infer from "Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members. " to know that these operators do not expect a pointer to members.

Comment: @jackX: I’m glad people appreciate that beast!  Meanwhile: there are no “member types”.  Even a non-static member function has the type expected from its declaration alone, with no provision for `this` aside from the special (and optional) *cv*- and ref-qualifiers allowed on such types.  Pointer-to-member is just a separate family of (families of) types related only in that they can be null.

Comment: Aha, the beast eliminated so many bugs...      It sounds like `pointer to member` is actually not considered as a "pointer". Merely, this type name has a text `pointer` and it can be null. So, whenever the rule says about the pointer, we should first expel `pointer to member` except the rule explicitly says about that.