# Lifetime of variable introduced by structured binding

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

What's the scope/lifetime of the uniquely named variable introduced by a structured binding declaration?

[[decl.struct.bind]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind)

> A structured binding declaration introduces the identifiers `v0`, `v1`, `v2`, … of the *identifier-list* as names of structured bindings.
> Let *cv* denote the *cv-qualifiers* in the *decl-specifier-seq* and *S* consist of the *storage-class-specifiers* of the *decl-specifier-seq* (if any).
> A *cv* that includes `volatile` is deprecated; see [depr.volatile.type].
> First, a variable with a unique name *e* is introduced.
> If the *assignment-expression* in the initializer has array type *cv1* `A` and no *ref-qualifier* is present, *e* is defined by
>
> *attribute-specifier-seq_opt S cv* `A e ;`
>
> [...]

The following paragraphs talk about the initialization of this variable. But it's not explicitly spelled out what the lifetime is, apart from the storage class which might give it static/thread/... storage duration.

Can we assume that the scope of *e* is the scope within which the structured binding appears? And similarly, the scope of the identifiers (though they don't have a lifetime as far as I understand)?

Is this generally implied for any "implicit" declaration (e.g. range-based for loop)?

```
struct s { int x; int y; };
s bar();

void foo()
{
  {
    auto [x, y] = bar();
  } // "e" destroyed at the end of this scope
}
```

Comment: If you follow the link to [storage-class-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#2), you'll end up at the statement [no other storage class specifier appears](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#2) then you will get "automatic storage". So the lifetime will be limited to the current scope.

Comment: _But it's not explicitly spelled out what the lifetime is_ Because variables do not have it

Comment: _Can we assume that the scope of e is the scope within which the structured binding appears?_ I'd say, it'd be better to be specified. Not sure if this will be considered  an editorial fix

Comment: You can see using the site https://cppinsights.io/ exactly what is happening

Comment: @Don'tDownVote The replacement code it shows is not equivalent to the structured binding in many details. This is a demonstration/learning tool. It can't answer nuanced specification questions.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer *"Because variables do not have it"* Could you please elaborate? I don't get what you mean. Objects have lifetime but not variables?

Comment: Sorry to not being able to back this up with a quote from the standard. But I seem to remember that x and y may be termed "aliases" in this case. Lifetime-wise the returned instance of s lives in the assignment line, in principle. However, attaching the aliases to it extends it's lifetime to match that of the aliases. Having the destructor of s doing console output at least proves, that the instance lives exactly till the end of the block: https://godbolt.org/z/froh6Tqea

Comment: @kaba The question is where/how the standard specifies this lifetime. The `language-lawyer` tag indicates that the question is about the specification, not any practical application. Also, they are not called alias. They are called _structured bindings_. There is no assignment in the code either. And lifetime extension is not relevant here, because there is no temporary object.

Comment: @dyp Objects have lifetime. A variable as an entity is (or shouldn't be) an object, in particular generally not a single one, and therefore shouldn't have an associated lifetime. A block-scope non-reference variable should for example correspond to a new object each time its scope is entered, each of which have a lifetime. But the standard conflates "variable" and "object" into one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319283/how-to-understand-the-concept-of-variable.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of the variable *e* specified by [[dcl.struct.bind]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind) is governed by other language rules. *e* is declared where the structured binding declaration appears. In your case, that means *e* is declared in the innermost block of `foo`, and it has the same lifetime as any other variable declared in the innermost block of `foo`. The same goes for its scope, although since you can't name *e* directly, you can't observe its scope.

Comment: If the structured binding is in a block scope, the lifetime is an observable manifestation of the scope via [stmt.dcl]/2.

Comment: *"e is declared where the structured binding declaration appears."* I guess that part is implied in "First, a variable with a unique name *e* is introduced [into the same scope as the structured binding declaration]"?

Comment: @dyp I believe that's the intent, yes.